# left align under 600 px

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I am not quite sure why my logo on my [Test site](http://vouzalis.com/public.html) is left aligning when I go under 600px in screen width? I do not have any `float left` and I centered the picture with `text-align: center` also.

**I am building an email newsletter template. Therefore I use the foundation css framework, and that means tables.**

Can anybody see why my logo is left align below 600px?

**HTML**

```
<!-- Logo -->
          <table class="row background-color__white">
            <tr>
              <td class="center" align="center">
                <center>
                  <table class="container">
                    <tr>
                      <td class="wrapper last">
                        <table class="twelve columns">
                          <tr>
                            <td style="text-align: center;">
                              <a href="http://google.dk">
                                <img width="250" height="80" src="https://s24.postimg.org/y6ho747xx/Untitled_1.png" alt="Alt text here">
                              </a>
                            </td> 
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </center>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
```

Comment: 1. Please provide a [mcve]. 2. No need for all that bold text.

Comment: I have posted before, where other people complaint about that I had to set bold text, when I wrote that I was programming for emails. People got angry that I used tables. So from that time I did what other people said I should do. Now I have to do the same I did in the start again.

Comment: Were you posting code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table, tr, and td tags have display: table-row, they need to be turned into display: block. If you need them only for media queries, then stick this in there.

```
#test, #test table, #test td, #test tr, #test tbody {
  display: block;
}
```

Updated with a jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/cj09ecy2/

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is that gonna effect other things in my code?

Comment: Ah okay just tried that. So the whole website went left aligned :)

Comment: Yes it will effect every table, tr, and td tag. If you only want it to effect  where the logo is then use the .row class. So .row td, .row tr, or simply use an ID in the the start of the table and do it that way

Comment: use in your scenario #test, #test td, #test tr, #test table, #test tbody { display: block }

Comment: I updated with a fiddle, look at the top line in css

Comment: Okay even if it is against my principle, then I copy/pasted your code. And it is working perfect now, and I can also use it for my buttons. It does not seem that it affects some other things, so I say thank you a lot :-)

Answer (score 1):

In Zurb, below 600 means that a media query is setting your  cell to be align="left". That means either the href, td, tr or table places an align="left" on your table cell.

You can force the logo to align center by placing the same center style to each parent above the td.

```
<table align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" class="twelve columns" style="text-align: center;">
  <tr style="text-align: center;">
    <td style="text-align: center;">
      <a href="http://google.dk">
        <img width="250" height="80" src="https://s24.postimg.org/y6ho747xx/Untitled_1.png" alt="Alt text here">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can also add a class like `.center-align {text-align: center !important;}` and add that to your class in the td as well as the media query for under 600.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the answer. Sounds like you have a lot of knowledge with Zurb. I just tried what you said, but sorry the image still keeps jumping to the left: http://vouzalis.com/public-1.html

Comment: on line 326, copy table.body and create this tag instead:

`table.body {
    text-align: center !important;
}`

Leave it somewhere below line 326 so it's read last.

Comment: There is something totallt wrong here. I did what you wrote, but it is just still the same. http://vouzalis.com/public-1.html . I cannot figure this out anymore

Comment: I understand. I edited my comment. Give it a try. It's working when I do it.

Comment: Thank you again. I just tried to make a jsfiddle with your code. https://jsfiddle.net/rbzcdbvz/ . It is not working there either :-(

Comment: Try adding the style `text-align: center !important;` to the td. If that doesn't work, apply it to the tr, then the Table. The table.body has a text-align: left as a default. Something, either that class or another one is asserting control which is keeping the `text-align: left.` I have this issue with a right-aligned logo and this is how I fixed it in every email client.