# Image align left under 600 px

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

This question has been marked as a dublicate. The other question did not solve my problem.

The logo image in the top on this page: [My Site Example](http://vouzalis.com/public.html) is align left, when I go under `600px;`. I am programing for email newsletters, and therefore I am using the foundation framework with CSS and tables.

I cannot customize a lot in the CSS, because the email clients have problem rendering some custom code. I found out earlier where a user on Stackoverflow suggested an idea. I notice than when I delete the second line in the css @media, the logo is going almost to center, but is not responsive.

The [foundation framework](http://foundation.zurb.com/emails/docs/alignment.html) apparently left align everything, when the screensize is under 600px. But I cannot find anything on the documentation which says how to overrule that.

Does anybody have a creative idea, which dont require a lot of custom code, so I do not mess up the foundation framework?

**CSS**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {

  table[class="body"] img {
    width: auto !important;
    height: auto !important;
  }
  <!-- Second Line -->
  table[class="body"] center {
    min-width: 0 !important;
  }
```

**HTML (Relevant code)**

```
<!-- Logo -->
          <table class="row background-color__white" id="component-center">
            <tr>
              <td class="center" align="center">
                <center>
                  <table align="center" class="container">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td>
                          <table class="row">
                            <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                <th class="small-12 large-12 columns first last">
                                  <table>
                                    <tr>
                                      <th>
                                        <center data-parsed="">
                                          <img src="http://placehold.it/200?text=center" alt="image of clever meme that made me chuckle" align="center" class="float-center">
                                        </center>
                                      </th>
                                      <th class="expander"></th>
                                    </tr>
                                  </table>
                                </th>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </center>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [left align under 600 px](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41964378/left-align-under-600-px)

Comment: Hello. It is correct that this question was the one I thought solved the problem. I refer to that question in my new question here.

Comment: You accepted an answer on that question which allowed us to mark this as duplicate. Please refer to your original post if your issue has not been resolved. Or, if you have a new issue, ask away!

Comment: That question also solved my problem I thought, but this question is different because I have a lot of different code now. It is impossible to keep on asking in the old question. It would not make sense for anybody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is the exact same answer as last time. Except now the answer to your problem has moved to public.html:837. The parent element can influence the element below it.

In this case, you have an href wrapping the image. If you look at your css code on line 837, you'll see this, pared down to the text-align:

`body, table.body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, td, th, a {
    text-align: left;
}`

Above the href is a th. It is also `text-align: left;` If you specify this style on each line: `style="text-align: center !important;"`, it will over-ride the text-align: left.

I am an email developer and I do this with Zurb Foundation for emails every day. I understand the problem and face it constantly, only I'm trying to push things to the right. Please give this a try.